# latest ffmpeg compile produces buzzing audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I used the autobuilder to update ffmpeg and now any and all aac audio encoded with HE-v2 is one long, continuous buzz.  HE-v1 is unaffected and produces the expected results, but no matter how I change the settings, or how often I recompile, HE-v2 results in the "bee" sounds.

Reverting to the previous version solves the problem but also removes some of the new features I wanted.  My command line is

```
ffmpeg -i "%input%" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 48k -ac 2 -profile:a aac_he_v2 -t 30 "%output%"
```

and the console output is:

```
ffmpeg version N-86515-g478a1949d9 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration:  --enable-avisynth --enable-gcrypt --enable-libmp3lame --enable
-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-cuda --en
able-cuvid --enable-schannel --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree -
-disable-debug
  libavutil      55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavcodec     57. 99.100 / 57. 99.100
  libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 92.100 /  6. 92.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'Test.wav':
  Duration: 00:03:12.44, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, ipod, to 'Test.m4a':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.73.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 H
z, stereo, s16, 48 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.99.100 libfdk_aac
size=     180kB time=00:00:30.02 bitrate=  49.2kbits/s speed=40.6x
video:0kB audio:177kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
overhead: 1.846480%
```

Is there any way to fix this, or to swap out this version of libfdk_aac for something slightly earlier but which still works?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the FDK encoder. Your compile may have produced a standalone encoder. If so, run and check output of

```
fdkaac -p 29 -b 48000 -o test.m4a in.wav
```

where in.wav is your 30 second sample. Once you have verified the output is broken, open an issue at https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac/issues

---

Workaround is to use an older revision of the library

In the compile script `build/media-suite_compile.sh`, change

`if do_vcs "https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac"; then`

to

`if do_vcs "https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac#commit=50922e3d"; then`

Comment: I had declined the option to make standalones during compile but will re-run it.